# ILogger accessing params args in the function Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am implementing a custom ILogger in .Net Core 3.1. The class needs to implement the following contract

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
```

I am triggering the LogDebug function and passing a list of tuple (key, value) arguments like this:

```
logger.LogDebug("MyDebugMessage", ("arg1Key", "arg2Value"), ("arg2Key", "arg2Value"), ("arg3Key", "arg3Value"));
```

The ILogger Log function is triggered and the first parameter the message "MyDebugMessage" is passed into the state parameter. However there is no variable for the list of arguments in the ILogger function.
How can I access the list of arguments?

Comment: Try something like this :            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() {
                 new KeyValuePair<string,string>("arg1Key", "arg2Value"), 
                 new KeyValuePair<string,string>("arg2Key", "arg2Value"), 
                 new KeyValuePair<string,string>("arg3Key", "arg3Value")
            };
            string message = string.Join(";", values.Select(x => string.Format("{0},{1}", x.Key, x.Value)));

Comment: Thanks @jdweng for your reply. How can I access the values inside the public void Log<TState> method?

Comment: The results of the logger get put into a file.

Comment: I am using a custom logger so I implemented the ILogger method inside the custom class. When logging occurs this method is called inside the custom logger. But I am unable to access the passed in values. Hence, my question is how can I access the passed in values inside the custom class.

Comment: It is a dictionary.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-the-custom-loggerprovider

Answer (score 7):

So far I've found that the only way is to use reflection to get the _values private member of TState state.

```
  public class ApiLogger : ILogger
  {
       // more code 

       public async void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
       {  
               
           FieldInfo[] fieldsInfo = state.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
           FieldInfo props = fieldsInfo.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == "_values");
           object[] values = (object[])props?.GetValue(state);

           // more code 
       }

       // more code 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The default object passed to "TState state" is
[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.FormattedLogValues](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/Internal/FormattedLogValues.cs)

which is derived from type IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>

you can get the kvp list of arguments from it

Comment: this would be the cleanest solution short of using a custom TState, unfortunately "FormattedLogValues is inaccessible due to its protection level" :( is there something I'm missing? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The hack with Reflection described by Hugo does no longer work in .net core 7

I think the 'params object[]? args' parameter was never intended for passing additional data to your ILogger.Log implementation but is only intended for formatting the message.

So I came up with a alternative solution.

I make use of the EventId parameter that I normally do not use. The EventId is an object with an int Id and string Name property. This Name property can be filled with whatever string you like. I simple create a typed object and serialize to json. Create an instance of the EventId class with a irrelevant Id property and the Name set to my json.

In your ILogger.Log implementation I simply deserialize the eventId.Name to its typed class and I have typed access to the data I want to pass.

You could use the Id property to tell the receiving side what kind of object can be deserialized from the Name property. That way you can pass serveral object types.

Comment: Agree, I was thinking the same and implemented using EventId. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recently was trying to access the arguments passed into a custom ILogger as well when I ran across this question. I struggled to find a solution online.

It took me a few hours to solve my problem, which turned out to be a pretty simple solution. Maybe it will help you.

To get the info out of TState state in public void Log in my custom logger, I did the following:

```
    var jsonState = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state);

    Console.WriteLine($"TesterLogger: {jsonState}");
```

Then I deserialize the jsonState like this:

```
    var kvpState = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(jsonState);
```

Also, I grab the interpolated message like this:

```
    var message = state?.ToString() ?? "";

    Console.WriteLine(message);
```

I've tested this in .NET 6 and 7. It seems to work fine in both.

Answer (score 0):

As Williwyg pointed out there is no way to access the 'params object[]? args' in your custom implementation.
However there is a much cleaner way to pass the custom data.

The logger.LogDebug is implemented as an extension method. So you should implement your own extension and pass to it whatever you want:

```
public static void LogMyDebug(this ILogger logger, int EventID, Dictionary<string, string> myData)
{
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, EventID, myData, null,
        (data, exception) => string.Join(";", myData.Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value).ToArray()));
}
```

Now in the custom implementation of ILogger, in the:

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
```

your dictionary will appear in the 'state' parameter and you will be able to cast it back to the dictionary.

The 'formatter' is provided for compatibility, so the other providers will be able to log your custom messages and your implementation will be able to log all messages.

So you have to check whether the 'state' contains your dictionary or not. If it isn't you need to use the provided formatter to prepare the message. Of Course in this case it will be lacking your custom data.