# How to access a Dictionary<string, string> from the state-parameter in a custom ILogger Log-method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, ilogger

I'm currently working on a custom ILogger-implementation, and want to be able to pass custom logging parameters as a Dictionary<string, string>. So I call the Ilogger's log function like this:

```
var customParameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" } };
_logger.LogInformation("Testmessage, customParameters: {customParameters}", customParameters);
```

The question I have is how do I access the actual Dictionary in the ILogger `Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)` method? It seems to end up in the TState parameter, but I can't figure out how to actually extract the Dictionary from there.

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211201/ilogger-accessing-params-args-in-the-function-logtstateloglevel-loglevel